# Cannot load extensions/cogs in Discord.py anymore on version

Tags: discord, discord.py

Code (most of it is hidden):

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = discord.Client(
    intents=intents,
    description='REDACTED',
    case_insensitive=True,
    owner_id=REDACTED
)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name} - {bot.user.id}')

bot.load_extension(cogs.Mod)
bot.run("token")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Personal\discord-bots\quantum.py\quantum.py", line 18, in <module>
    bot.load_extension(cogs.Mod)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'load_extension'
```

I was trying to be able to use the <bot/client>.load_<extension/cog>() prompt, but it didn't work all of a sudden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the current version of discord.py (2.1.0), you can only call load_extension on a `discord.ext.commands.Bot` (see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension)

As per the API documentation:

> This class is a subclass of discord.Client and as a result anything that you can do with a discord.Client you can do with this bot.

So you shouldn't have any trouble replacing `discord.Client` with a `commands.Bot` in your existing code.